# VBA replacing all matches in the table (Word)

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have a table in Word, in the 3rd row I have "1. Text" I'm trying to delete the dot. I know that it can be done without vba, I'm just practicing on something simple.

```
Sub Test()

Dim replacePattern As String
Dim RE As RegExp
Set RE = New RegExp

RE.Pattern = "(^[0-9]).(\s[A-Za-z\s]*)"
RE.Global = True
replacePattern = "$1$2"

Set Matches = RE.Execute(Selection.Text)
For Each Match In Matches
    Selection.Text = RE.Replace(Selection.Text, replacePattern)
Next
End Sub
```

Right now it replaces text only in the first selected cell. How can I do it properly?

Comment: Try adding `RE.Multiline = True`. Also, escape the `.`, `RE.Pattern = "^([0-9])\.(\s[A-Za-z\s]*)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part here is working with text in table cells.
The way you are doing it now will remove a lot of the table information and you will end up with a garbled document.
If you do it cell by cell, it'll be easier:

```
For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each Cell In Table.Range.Cells
        Set Matches = RE.Execute(Cell.Range.Text)
        For Each Match In Matches
            Cell.Range.Text = RE.Replace(Cell.Range.Text, replacePattern)
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: This should be done using a wildcard Word search. The Table range can be obtained quite easily via selection.Tables(1).range, assuming that the current selection point is in a Table.